# Is there any agile web project management "tutorials"?

Tags: agile

I've read many resources on the web about agile web project management and I think I understand the theory behind it. Now I would like to find few examples built like full "tutorials" in order to be able to mentally map theory into practice. Unfortunately, I am yet to find anything mixing theory and practice in great depth.

They need to cover at least those areas:

- **gathering information** from the customer (product vision, what problem
  does it solve or need that it covers)
- writing **user stories/cases**
- **estimations** (development, testing, deployment, bug fixing, risks)
- detailed **specification** for first iteration

It doesn't matter if they are from books, websites or videos as soon as they cover everything from start to at least the end of the first iteration. Also, I know the term "agile" is pretty vague, but any iterative style will do.

If this is not appropriate question for this group, please forgive me and tell me where can I find answers or ask this question.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Adnac, welcome to PMSE! My suggestion is instead of focusing on using us to find examples for you, maybe focus on asking specifically about where you're confused or lost. Not only would this be a more specific question, but you could even use that as an opportunity to ask several, more targeted questions about areas where you're struggling. Hope this helps and good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

A different approach could be to look at something like the [Scrum Kick-off planner](http://weisbart.com/kickoff/). It may help you "get ready" for agile.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a web tutorial it might be better for you to try a simple real-life exercise. For example, you could plan out your next vacation or dinner date with your significant other using an agile approach. You can work with him/her on visioning, user stories etc etc and work through at least a couple of iterations. Approaching learning from this angle has the advantages of:

- Being relevant to you and therefore giving you more interest and engagement in the process.
- Forcing you to deal with real human beings, which is the real challenge of project management.
- Avoiding situations where you don't understand the technical aspects referred to in a tutorial.
- Giving you a wider breadth of opportunity to make a variety of mistakes, which gives you experience to learn from.

Comment: Thank you for your input but the question is related to web projects and asks for examples of how to put theory into practice. What you are saying is valid though, but still unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

We've found that there aren't a lot of resources specifically around Agile and web project management which is why we launched an [Agile Web Project Management training course](http://www.emarketeers.com/training-courses/agile-web-project-management).

You may also want to try joining some LinkedIn groups around Agile. The groups I've joined appear to have lots of daily discussion around people's Agile Web PM experiences.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a series about this topic a while ago:

- [XP with Kanban instead of Scrum](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2011/02/xp-with-kanban-instead-of-scrum/): moving from Scrum to Kanban
- [Kanban Nightmares](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2010/11/kanban-nightmares/): failing with Kanban and recovery
- [Pimp my Team](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2011/02/pimp-my-team/): rethinking Kanban

Answer (score 1):

Some good podcasts on Agile Weekly can also help- http://integrumtech.com/category/agile-weekly-podcast/

I discovered them a few days back and have been listening to regularly now.